# How can I query Dynamics 365 CRM as the logged in user in an ASP.NET MVC site authenticated with AAD?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I have an ASP.NET MVC website. Locally, and when deployed to Azure, it authenticates users in our organization with Azure Active Directory. Once authenticated, `User.Identity` is a `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity`.

I can query Dynamics CRM (hosted in the cloud, so Dynamics 365 CRM online) by embedding a username and password into the connection string and using `Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient` namespace. The connection string looks like:

> "Url=https://organization.crm.dynamics.com;
> Username=user@organizationURL.com; Password=passwordhere;
> authtype=Office365"

...but I want to avoid creating an application user account and I'd prefer to use the ambient security identity to connect to CRM as the authenticated user. How can I do this? Am I using the wrong SDK or package? I'm having a hard time finding a modern example or documentation that is intended for programmers rather than IT configuration.

When registering the website in Azure, I indicated that the user will need grant permission to interact with Dynamics CRM on their behalf, and I was prompted for this permission when I logged in, but as the programmer, I'm not sure how to actually use this permission.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use CRM REST web api along with a header `CallerObjectId` (for impersonation) which is guid of current logged-in user Azure AD object id. This will make sure the api call is made in user context. Of course you have to use AAD challenge/SSO in your MVC website and/or graph api capture the current AAD user guid.

Example payload:

```
POST [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/accounts HTTP/1.1  
CallerObjectId: e39c5d16-675b-48d1-8e67-667427e9c084  
Accept: application/json  
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8  
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0  
OData-Version: 4.0  
  
{"name":"Sample Account created using impersonation"}
```

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/impersonate-another-user-web-api#how-to-impersonate-a-user)

Still you have to use Application user for generating token and access the web api.

Answer (score 2):

(My reputation is too low to comment, so I'll add this as an answer instead)

I agree with Arun's recommendation to use the CRM REST web api along with CallerObjectId.
But I don't think it is necessary to use AAD challenge/SSO in your MVC website. If you $select the property azureactivedirectoryobjectid from /api/data/v9.1/systemusers you should find the needed AAD user guid there.